# Angular4 angularfire2

Tags: angular

I'm on a project angular4 and since I can not make the compilations because of this error met about angularfire2.
Someone could help me please.

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(5,45): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(8,17): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(9,21): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(11,20): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(13,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(8,43): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(9,46): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(9,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,49): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,95): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,140): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,182): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,49): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,94): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,130): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(8,54): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(8,96): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(10,19): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(12,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(12,69): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(13,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(14,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(15,30): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(16,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(17,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(8,10): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(9,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(10,28): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(14,42): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(9,55): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(12,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(4,11): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(5,14): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(14,37): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(14,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(16,10): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(17,12): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(6,41): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(6,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(7,41): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(7,98): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(8,48): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(8,93): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.

ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(5,45): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(8,17): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(9,21): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(10,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(11,20): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(13,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(8,43): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(9,46): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(9,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,49): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,95): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,140): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(10,182): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,49): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,94): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(11,130): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(8,54): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(8,96): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(10,19): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(12,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(12,69): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(13,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(14,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(15,30): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(16,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(17,27): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(8,10): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(9,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(10,28): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(14,42): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(9,55): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(12,25): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(4,11): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(5,14): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(14,37): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(14,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(16,10): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(17,12): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(6,41): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(6,80): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(7,41): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(7,98): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(8,48): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(8,93): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'firebase'.
```

Comment: Please show the part of your code where you import firebase.

Comment: check your ```package.json``` versions, make sure you are using ```firebase 4.8.0``` with ```angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.4```

Comment: My firebase version is 4.8.1 and angularfire2 remains the same.

Comment: here is the part where I import firebase

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

Comment: in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 6):

Go back to firebase 4.8.0 if your version 4.8.1:

1. Inside package.json, remove ^ from "firebase": "^4.8.1".
   Then Downgrade Firebase from 4.8.1 to 4.8.0 by changing 4.8.1 to 4.8.0 .
   End result should look like this: "firebase": "4.8.0".
2. Run npm update in the Project Root. NPM will downgrade Firebase for you.
3. Run ng serve --open to check for compilation errors. There shouldn't be any.
4. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

To install angularfire2 with angular 4:

> 1. npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
> 2. copy the below code to environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
firebase: {
apiKey: 'xxx',
authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
projectId: 'xxx',
storageBucket: 'xxx.appspot.com',
messagingSenderId: 'xxx'
}
};
```

> 3. Import AngularFireModule, AngularFireDatabaseModule and AngularFireAuthModule from angularfire2 and environment to get the Firebase setup.

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
```

> 4. Then add modules in NgModule. It is possible to customize your Firebase name using ‘initialiazeApp’

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'letslearn-dev'),
AngularFireDatabaseModule,
AngularFireAuthModule
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> 5. Create an AuthService to manage authentication

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export class AuthService {
private authState: Observable<firebase.User>
private currentUser: firebase.User = null;
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
this.authState = this.afAuth.authState;
this.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.currentUser = user;
  } else {
    this.currentUser = null;
  }
});
}
getAuthState() {
return this.authState;
}
}
```

> 6. Inject your Firebase Auth service in your app component.

```
import { AuthService } from './shared/auth.service';
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
user = null;
constructor(
private auth: AuthService) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.auth.getAuthState().subscribe(
  (user) => this.user = user);
}
}
```

> Hopes this will solve your problem.